# unable to loop over data frame row index in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R which is of size nx4. I am attempting to loop through it and perform a computation to add to the "distances" vector. x0 is a vector of length 3. I attempt to run the following code

```
trainData = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)

for (j in 1:n) {
    distances[j] = sqrt(sum((x0 - trainData[j,1:3])^2))
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(x0, trainData[j, 1:3]) : 
  ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

However, the 2 values being subtracted are the same length, and I can run it without looping, ie

```
sqrt(sum((x0 - trainData[1,1:3])^2))
```

I'm unable to find the reason for this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` (not `str` or `head` or picture/screenshot) so others can help. 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: Perhaps `n <- nrow(trainData)` before the loop? Close vote because we cannot tell what your x0 value might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `dist()` function to calculate your distance. Also, avoid using loops and look at the `apply` family of functions.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1724)
trainData <- data.frame(x1 = runif(4, 1, 10), x2 = runif(4, 1, 10), x3 = runif(4, 1, 10), y = runif(4, 1, 10))

mutate(trainData,
       dist = apply(trainData,
                    1,
                    function(x, y = runif(3, 1, 10)) {
                      dist(rbind(x[1:3], y), method = "euclidean")
                    }))

#         x1       x2       x3        y      dist
# 1 5.890667 7.156956 6.946917 6.580706  6.188533
# 2 3.060810 1.117295 7.676836 7.965404  5.193822
# 3 8.058110 5.518819 2.687567 3.832825 10.520283
# 4 8.405847 1.326119 3.533277 6.804517  8.390918
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the original issue was, but I've got things working by taking Paul's advice and replacing the loop with:

```
  distances = apply(trainData, 1, function(x) dist(rbind(x0,x)))
```